# Recover dropped database in mySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I accidentally dropped a database in my local mySQL using mysqlworkbench.

Any possibility to recover it? I am using windows 10.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have a back up

Comment: See this answer. This may help https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23251/is-there-a-way-to-recover-a-dropped-mysql-database

Comment: @P.Salmon yes! unfortunately